# Inference not working

Tags: drools, inference

I'm relatively new to Drools. I have those rules :

```
import models.Demarche;
declare IsMarque
 demarche : Demarche
end 

rule "Add type Marque taxe"
salience 2
no-loop true
lock-on-active true
when
    $d : Demarche( typeDemarche == "Marque" )
then
    modify($d){
        listTaxes.put(14, 1)
    }
    insert( new IsMarque( $d ) );
    System.out.println("infer marque");
end
```

And :

```
rule "Add Marque Polynesie extention taxe"
no-loop true
lock-on-active true
when
    $d : Demarche( extPolynesie == true)
    IsMarque(demarche == $d)
then
    $d.listTaxes.put(17, 1);
    System.out.println("marque");
end



rule "Add Not Marque Polynesie extention taxe"
no-loop true
lock-on-active true
when
    $d : Demarche( extPolynesie == true)
    not(IsMarque(demarche == $d))
then

    System.out.println("not marque");
end
```

For the rules 2 or 3, nothing happens. One of them should be true, but nothing is printed, as if the infered IsMarque cannot be evaluated. If I comment the IsMaqrue evaluation this is working, i can see the messages printed in the console.
Any idea?

Comment: Whatever makes you use lock-on-active? Remove this. -- Apart from that, you can't be sure that the first rule fires on a  Demarche where extPolynesie is true, which would be required for rules #2 and #3. If you still have problems with lock-on-active removed: please add your code inserting facts.

Comment: If i remove lock-on-active my rules are in an infinite loop. And yes i'm sure that my demarche is extPolynesie = true, in my DB i have only one demarche (in which extPolynesie is true)

Comment: Loop: if so, you haven't shown all of what you do on the right hand side. -1

Comment: extPolynesie: Maybe there will be another Demarche in WM some day? You better make your constraints proof.

Comment: I've edited my post to show the missing parts, i make changes on the evaluated demarche that's why i'm in an infinite loop. And yes obviously one day i will have a extPolynesie = false, but for now i just try to make it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule needs to be rewritten as

```
rule "Add type Marque taxe"
when
    $d : Demarche( typeDemarche == "Marque", $t:  listTaxes)  // I AM GUESSING HERE
    not IsMarque(demarche == $d)
then
    modify($t){
        put(14, 1)
    }
    insert( new IsMarque( $d ) );
    System.out.println("infer marque");
end
```

And no `no-loop true` and `lock-on-active true` **if you have shown everything there is.**

Note that you could write the first rule also as

```
rule "Add type Marque taxe"
when
    $d : Demarche( typeDemarche == "Marque")
then
    $d.getListTaxes().put(14, 1);
    insert( new IsMarque( $d ) );
    System.out.println("infer marque");
end
```

if (and only if) no other rule as CEs referring to the listTaxes property. Since you have used this "dirty update" in rule `"Add Marque Polynesie extention taxe"`, it seems to be OK.

Please post complete rules - #1 doesn't compile.

Comment: Thx, actually i've used a global list for adding my taxes, but this was the good way, not updating the evaluated object, and drop the no loop and lock on active. Thx :)